# What is rgb formula for a gradient going from white to blue?

Tags: language-agnostic, colors, rgb

I want to have a button that has numbers in the range 0 ... 255. I'd like the color of the button to be white when it's zero and blue (RGB = (0,0,255)) when it is 255. How can I accomplish this? At first I tried to make it RGB = (0,0,0) in the beginning, but it will only make it black.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simple linear interpolation between white (255,255,255) and blue (0,0,255) will do.

Answer (score 8):

A gradient from blue to white would start with:

0,0,255

with values of the R and G increasing at the same rate:
1,1,255
...
10,10,255
...
255,255,255

The colors between the 2 will start to appear pastel blue, then greyish blue.

Comment: The question was about white to blue, not blue to white.

Answer (score 2):

```
whitebluegradient(n):
    if n <   0: n = 0
    if n > 255: n = 255
    r = 255-n
    g = r
    b = 255
    return rgb (r,g,b)
```

This will give (255,255,255 = white) for `n = 0` and (0,0,255 = blue) for `n = 255`.

Answer (score 1):

white in RGB is 255,255,255

So, just decrese red and green

Answer (score 1):

Set R & G to (255 - the value of the button).

255,255,255 = white
0,0,255 = blue